# Cross Site Scripting injection

Tags: javascript, xss

I am testing a web application. I want to write an `XSS` script that will display an alert `"Hello"`.

The first script I wrote was:

```
<script >alert("Hello");</script >
```

But did not display the alert `"Hello"`. I discovered that the `XSS` script that works is

```
<SCRIPT >alert(String.fromCharCode(72,101,108,108,111,33))</SCRIPT >
```

***I would like to know why the first script didn't work.***

Comment: If you want to know more about XSS obfuscation I can suggest you the [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) .

Comment: I'm not sure why haven't you accepted the answer yet. It seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely that site replaces double quotes with HTML entities or tries to escape them in some other way that makes them unsuitable for JavaScript.
When using `String.fromCharCode(...)` you don't have to use any quotation marks so it'll work. It gets a list of the ASCII codes of the string's characters and creates a string out of them during runtime. So there's no need for any quoting.

The proper way to avoid this kind of XSS is to replace `<` with `&lt;` - that way a script tag cannot be created at all.

Note that `>`, `"` and `&` should also be replaced with their respective HTML entities when sanitizing data containing HTML! However, only `<` is absolutely required to defeat XSS attacks assuming no untrusted data can be used in HTML attributes (that's where `"` needs to be sanitized)

Comment: Yes @ThiefMaster, the site changes "Hello" in the first script to \"Hello\" . I would like to know why the site does this. Also, I would like to know how 'String.fromCharCode(72,101,108,108,111,33)' works to display Hello!

Comment: `String.fromCharCode` is a normal JavaScript method (explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)). You can use any JavaScript code inside your `<script>` environment.

Comment: There is absolutely no way for someone without access to the site's code to know why they escape double quotes with a backslash. Usually only single quotes are escaped that way to use them in a SQL query when parametrized queries are not an option. I already explained the reason why it works with `String.fromCharCode` above.