# XSS Injection in HTML textarea

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi, xss

I am trying to implement a functionality, similar to this *demo*: http://www.steve.org.uk/Security/XSS/Tutorial/simple.html, where I accept user input in a textarea. I am using CGI and tried using the following code.

HTML code snippet:

```
<form action="test.cgi" method="post">
  Message:
  <textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

test.cgi code snippet:

```
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $text = $cgi->param("text");
print $text
```

I believe this won't work (will not display the pop up with the message Worked) if inserted in the textarea field with a simple user input as follows.

```
<script> alert("Worked") </script>
```

May I please know why? I am new to CGI. I apologize if the question is trivial. Furthermore, I apologize if this question has been answered before. I found this question ([Cross Site Scripting injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135678/cross-site-scripting-injection)), but may I please know how *demo* displayed the alert box in his script simple.cgi? Also, I may be wrong here but there is no reference to JavaScript used in his code to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
use HTML::Entities;

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $text = encode_entities($cgi->param("text"));
print $text
```

Comment: Hello, @Dienes. I am afraid this does not work as intended. It prints out <script> alert("Worked") </script> to the web browser. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Replace < and > character this &lt; and &gt; in $text variable